# spring-cloud-azure-feature-management with application.yaml

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-azure

I am attempting to implement a quick feature flag solution for my teams that run both .net core and java spring boot. I was able to easily get a solution running with .net core using [feature-management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core2x) and was excited to see the [spring equivalent](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/tree/master/spring-cloud-azure-feature-management) because I was hoping for essentially the same tooling for all teams.However, I am having a problem because I just want to start by providing the flag values in the application/bootstrap.yaml and it keeps yelling at me with the following error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration-com.microsoft.azure.spring.cloud.config.AppConfigurationProperties': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one config store has to be configured.
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one config store has to be configured.

So, my question is, how do I specify a provider for a local file rather than spring cloud config? I do not have that implemented and it will take too long for me to do so in my environment.

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem! I had an extra dependency that was not needed for what I was doing. Once I removed the following it worked fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```